# BigQuery - A way to generate timestamps based on hour/minute/seconds?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to generate sequential timestamps in BigQuery that is focused on hours, minutes, and seconds?

In BigQuery you can generate sequential dates by:

```
select *
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2016-10-18', '2016-10-19', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as day
```

This will generate the dates from 2016-10-18 to 2016-10-19 in date intervals

---

```
Row day  
1   2016-10-18   
2   2016-10-19
```

---

But let's say I want intervals in 15 minutes or 5 minutes, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, I would recommend "starring" the [feature request for `GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY`](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71693426) to express interest in having a function like this. Given `GENERATE_ARRAY`, though, the best option currently is to use a query of this form:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_ADD('2018-04-01', INTERVAL 15 * x MINUTE)
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 13)) AS x;
```

If you want a minute-based `GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY` equivalent, you can use a UDF like this:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION GenerateMinuteTimestampArray(
    t0 TIMESTAMP, t1 TIMESTAMP, minutes INT64) AS (
  ARRAY(
    SELECT TIMESTAMP_ADD(t0, INTERVAL minutes * x MINUTE)
    FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(t1, t0, MINUTE))) AS x
  )
);

SELECT ts
FROM UNNEST(GenerateMinuteTimestampArray('2018-04-01', '2018-04-01 12:00:00', 15)) AS ts;
```

This returns a timestamp for each 15-minute interval between midnight and 12 PM on April 1.

**Update**: You can now use the [`GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY` function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#generate_timestamp_array) in BigQuery. If you want to generate timestamps at intervals of 15 minutes, for example, you can use:

```
SELECT GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY('2016-10-18', '2016-10-19', INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Epochs seems like the way to go.

But requires to convert date to epoch first.

```
select TIMESTAMP_MICROS(CAST(day * 1000000 as INT64))
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1522540800, 1525132799, 900)) as day

Row f0_  
1   2018-04-01 00:00:00.000 UTC  
2   2018-04-01 00:15:00.000 UTC  
3   2018-04-01 00:30:00.000 UTC  
4   2018-04-01 00:45:00.000 UTC  
5   2018-04-01 01:00:00.000 UTC  
6   2018-04-01 01:15:00.000 UTC  
7   2018-04-01 01:30:00.000 UTC  
8   2018-04-01 01:45:00.000 UTC  
9   2018-04-01 02:00:00.000 UTC  
10  2018-04-01 02:15:00.000 UTC  
11  2018-04-01 02:30:00.000 UTC  
12  2018-04-01 02:45:00.000 UTC  
13  2018-04-01 03:00:00.000 UTC
```